# how to use expectationForPredicate and tap a button

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

How can I tap a button after check if it is enabled?

I found this sample here, but It didn't work for my case.

[Delay/Wait in a test case of Xcode UI testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182637/delay-wait-in-a-test-case-of-xcode-ui-testing)

**Here a part of code:**

```
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let button = app.buttons["Tap me"]
    let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
    expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: button){
        button.tap()
        return true
    }
 waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)
```

but my test fails by tapping of the button. 
Thanks

Comment: The code looks correct, I am guessing the button does not exist / cannot be found

Comment: Did you check if the button is nil?

Comment: Of the console: po button.enabled return true.

Comment: use the record function and make sure you are retrieving the button correctly

Comment: @simpleBob the button is correct. It isn't the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code sample doesn't check if the button is enabled, only if it exists.

The block that you pass into `expectationForPredicate` will be executed if the button exists, so the button will be tapped even if the button is disabled.

To include a check for the button being enabled:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let button = app.buttons["Tap me"]
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: button) {
    // If the button exists, also check that it is enabled
    if button.enabled {
        button.tap()
        return true
    } else {
        // Do not fulfill the expectation since the button is not enabled
        return false
    }
}
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)
```